# Is there a package for R that allows smoothing splines in GEE?

Tags: r, mixed-model, panel-data, splines, generalized-estimating-equations

I run into a problem where I would like to build a GEE in R with cubic regression splines (or any other spline type) for a longitudinal data set and an urgent need for grouping and multiple autocorrelation structures. However, I did not find any package capable allowing for that.

If anyone could give a suggestion for a suitable package, I would really appreciate that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `splines` package has natural splines (`ns`), B-splines (`bs`), and a few other types. You can just use them as transformations for the predictors in the model:

```
geese(y ~ ns(x, 3) + z, ...)
```

Comment: See the geepack package for `geese`